# jquery filter use of else statement if match returns false

Tags: jquery

I'm using jQuery .filter() to check if a dropdown menu's options match a given string. For example, look if the word book is one of the dropdown options values and set that option to selected.  Here is the code:

```
var bookType = "Fiction";
$("#mySelect option").filter(function() {
   return this.text == bookType; 
}).attr('selected', true);
```

This works well.  What I'd like to do next is hide a div on the page if the filter function returns false (no match).  Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can check the returned jQuery object to see any object is selected

```js
$('#test').change(function() {
  bookType = $(this).val();
  var $opts = $("#mySelect option").filter(function() {
    return this.text == bookType;
  }).prop('selected', true);

  $('div').toggle($opts.length > 0);
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="test">
  <option>Fiction</option>
  <option>Story</option>
  <option>A</option>
  <option>B</option>
</select>

<select id="mySelect">
  <option>Fiction</option>
  <option>Story</option>
</select>

<div>Toggle me</div>
```